# C# XMLWriter create WriteAttributeStringAsync

Tags: c#, xml, xmlwriter

Does anyone know how I can write this line with the XMLWriter?

```
<TextChild xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" dt:dt="string">User defined 3</TextChild>
```

Problem here is xmlns:**dt** and dt:**dt**.

Error Message: 'dt' is a duplicate attribute name.

```
await writer.WriteStartElementAsync(string.Empty, "TextChild", string.Empty);
await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync("xmlns", "dt", string.Empty, "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes");
await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync("dt", "dt", string.Empty, "boolean");
await writer.WriteStringAsync(name);
await writer.WriteEndElementAsync();//TextChild
```

Answer (score 0):

`xmlns:dt` is a namespace definition. This is not an attribute.
It does not need to be created manually. It is enough to specify the namespace when creating the attribute.

```
await writer.WriteStartElementAsync(null, "TextChild", null);
await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync("dt", "dt", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes", "string");
await writer.WriteStringAsync(name);
await writer.WriteEndElementAsync();
```